# Lambda calculus substitution rule explanation

Tags: substitution, lambda-calculus

One of the rules for the definition of substitution in the lambda-calculus is:

$$[x \mapsto s]y = y \ \text{  if } \ x \neq y$$

**But how can $x = y$?** After all I am not substituting $y$ for $s$, but $x$.

I think I am just confused with the notation but it seems quite essential, so I really want to understand this thoroughly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is subtle.

First, $[x \mapsto s]y$ stands for the term *obtained from $y$ by replacing $x$ with $s$*. So, I'm not a native English speaker but I would say that you are substituting $s$ for $x$ (in $y$) and not substituting $x$ for $s$.

Moreover, and most importantly for your question, $x$ and $y$ are meta-variables, *i.e.* are two (distinct) symbols that stand for two variables. It might happen that both symbols stand for the same variable (this is the case where $x = y$), so you have to take into account also that case (and clearly, $[x \mapsto s]y = s$ in that case).

When you define the language of the $\lambda$-calculus, you first fix a countably infinite set of variables. These variables are denoted by $x, y, z, \dots$ but *are not* $x, y, z, \dots$: indeed, $x, y, z, \dots$ are just symbols that stand for variables. This is the meaning of *meta-variables*.

Comment: So the rule $[x \mapsto s]x = s$ is just the counterpart, where the metavariables themselves are, in fact, the same.

And $[x \mapsto s]y ...$ covers the case where the metavariables are different, but (possibly) denote the same variables?

Comment: @NiklasVest - Yes and no. I mean, formally you are right but if in the definition of substitution the case $[↦]$ has two sub-cases depending on whether $=$ or $≠$, there is no point in considering also the case $[↦]$ because it coincides with the case $[↦]$ where $=$. In the definition of substitution (and more in general, in any definition by structural induction on a term), what matter are variables, not meta-variables (which are used only to talk about variables).